# Django Tests - User Factory with create_batch

Tags: python, django, testing, faker, factory-boy

Ok I've faced interesting problem with my tests files.

I'm using this simple code to check User's created by `UserFactory`

```
UserFactory.create_batch(4)

for u in User.objects.all():
    print(u.email)
```

**UserFactory - this works fine**

Creates 4 users in `create_batch(4)` process

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from factory import Faker
from factory.django import DjangoModelFactory

class UserFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    email = Faker("email")
    password = Faker(
        "password",
        length=42,
        special_chars=True,
        digits=True,
        upper_case=True,
        lower_case=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        django_get_or_create = ["email"]
```

**UserFactory - this one doesn't work**

Creates only 1 user in `create_batch(4)` process

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from faker import Faker
from factory.django import DjangoModelFactory

fake = Faker()

class UserFactory(DjangoModelFactory):

email = fake.email()
password = fake.password()

class Meta:
    model = get_user_model()
    django_get_or_create = ["email"]
```

The only difference is the way I generate user's email. `factory.Faker("email)` works fine but `faker.email()` doesn't.

Maybe someone had the same issue?

---

- factory_boy docs: https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html
- faker package docs: https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why are you not using `password = Faker("password")` in the second case?

Answer (score 3):

Your issue comes from the way Python works.

When you write the following:

```py
class Foo(Bar):
  email = fake.email()
  name = fake.name()
```

What happens is, more or less:

1. Python calls `fake.email()`, and receives a value (let's say `jane@example.org`)
2. Python calls `fake.name()`, and receives a value (for instance `"Johannes"`)
3. Python builds the dict of all class-level declarations for the target class — here `{"email": "jane@example.org", "name": "Johannes"}`
4. This is passed to `type` to create the class:

   ```py
   Foo = type(
     "Foo",  # Name of the class being created
     [Bar],  # List of its bases
     {"email": "jane@example.org", "name": "Johannes"},  # Methods & attributes
   )
   ```
5. The class is now defined, and available for the rest of the code.

In other words, the lines are executed as they would be for the following code:

```py
fake = faker.Faker()
fake_email = fake.email()
fake_name = fake.name()

class UserFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
  email = fake_email
  name = fake_name
  ...
```

As you can see, the `UserFactory` receives the *results* from the calls to faker, it has no way to know how those values were generated.

This is the reason for the various declarations (`factory.LazyAttribute`, `factory.Faker`, etc): here, we pass factory-specific objects with a custom method which is called by FactoryBoy's builder code whenever a new instance needs building:

```py
fake_email_maker = factory.Faker("email")
fake_name_maker = factory.Faker("name")

class UserFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
  email = fake_email_maker
  name = fake_name_maker
  ...
```

When you call `UserFactory()`, what happens looks like the following:

```py
# UserFactory()
>>> fields = {}
>>> fields["name"] = UserFactory._meta.declarations...name.evaluate(...)
>>> fields["email"] = UserFactory._meta.declarations...evaluate(...)
>>> return User.objects.create(**fields)
```

Comment: thank you for detailed answer. It's all clear now,

Answer (score 0):

The reason for getting the same password every time is that you're only getting the value of the call to `fake.password()`. That only gets called once, when the file is imported.

Answer (score 0):

Use `factory.LazyFunction(fake.name)` intead of `fake.name()` and don't add **()** when you wrappe with factory.LazyFunction.